# How to debug FactoryGirl.create callback errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

First problem is that FactoryGirl shows the error message but don't say where occurs, file and line:

I have a `byebug` in a very simply `spec` file:

```
RSpec.describe Site::HomeHelper, type: :helper do
  describe 'html meta description for products page' do
    context 'without categories' do
      it 'should return the family name and preference.meta_desc' do
        byebug
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And byebug here works, then within console I try:

```
(byebug) FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_one_company)
```

and the error message is

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass
```

**But I don't know where**

Then, trying to solve it, I put `byebug` in all places I think can cause this error, but I realised that with `FactoryGirl.create(:model)` byebug is not **triggered** (I'm almost sure in the past could used it)

So that, for example, in a simply working code like this

```
(byebug) FactoryGirl.create(:user).activation_code
```

with user model:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    before_create :set_activation_code
    private

    def set_activation_code
      byebug
      self.activation_code = 'IT IS EXECUTED'
    end
```

I get

```
(byebug) FactoryGirl.create(:user).activation_code
"IS EXECUTED"
```

and **byebug is not executed**, code program don't stop

I have checked Gemfile, to see if I had some gems not in development or test groups, and I think are ok:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails' #, '4.8.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing' # => 'assert_template'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
end
```

I think I'm missing something obvious. Thanks

---

Edited -> Factory code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: Constructor::User do
    password 'Elsevier'
    password_confirmation 'Elsevier'
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Pep#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "pep#{n}@gmail.com" }

    factory :user_without_password_confirmation do
      password_confirmation 'ElsevXXX'
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: can you please add the factory code? from your first example it seems that there might be an issue in your factory

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to run `FactoryGirl.create...` from `rails console`. Here I can see the error traces and also have access to byebug without problems.

To do this, just have in mind two things:

- `factory_girl_rails` gem must be in development group in Gemfile

  ```
    group :development, :test do'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails`
      gem 'byebug'...
    end
  ```
- when execute `FactoryGril.create` within `rails console` the tables are not automatically reset as it happens when run tests